# Why is UFD a Krull domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Matsumura mentions this as if it is obvious, and I can't find this result anywhere. Am I missing something obvious here?

Comment: Just found a proof in Kaplansky's Commutative Rings. I can't seem to delete this question, though.

Comment: I don't think it's necessary or even desirable to delete the question.  It's a very fair question for a reader of Matsumura (a standard text) to have.  The fact that it's answered somewhere else (it had better be, and of course it is) is nothing against answering it here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for completeness: A Krull domain is an integral domain $D$ with field of fractions $K$ for which there is a family $\mathcal{F}=\{R_{\lambda}\}_{\lambda\in\Lambda}$ of discrete valuation rings of $K$ such that:

1. $D = \mathop{\cap}\limits_{\lambda\in\Lambda}R_{\lambda}$; and
2. For every $x\in K$, $x\neq 0$, there are at most a finite number of $\lambda\in\Lambda$ such that $v_{\lambda}(x)\neq 0$.

So, assume that $D$ is a UFD. For each (class of associated) irreducible element $\pi$ of $D$, localizing away from $\pi$ (only allowable denominators are prime to $\pi$) gives you a DVR with valuation given by $(\pi)$. The intersection of all of these DVRs, viewed as subrings of the field of fractions of $D$, is exactly $D$ (because the only elements in the field of fractions that can be written with denominators prime to all irreducibles are the elements of $D$), and every element of the field of fractions has nonzero $\pi$-valuation only at finitely many $\pi$ (write the fraction in reduced terms: only those $\pi$ that show up in the numerator or the denominator give you nonzero valuation). So $D$ is a Krull ring.