# Is every field a Krull domain?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, definition

**Background**: A *Krull domain* is an integral domain $A$ with a family $(v_i)$ of valuations on the field of fractions $K$ for $A$ satisfying the following conditions:

1. Each $v_i$ is discrete.
2. The intersection of the valuation rings for the $v_i$ is $A$.
3. For every $x\in K^\times$, there are finitely many indices $i$ such that $v_i(x)\neq0$.

This definition is paraphrased from Bourbaki. We require discrete valuations to be nontrivial.

**Question**: Is every field a Krull domain?

**Concerns**: If a field $k$ were a Krull domain, the only way the definition could be satisfied would be if we took an empty family of valuations because of property 2. In this case, properties 1 and 3 hold trivially and 2 holds if we take the intersection over the empty set to be $k$. But I don't see how that argument uses field properties of $k$: it seems to show that any integral domain is Krull if we take an empty family of valuations.

**Motivation**: I'm working through the proof that a finite intersection of Krull domains (living in some common field) is a Krull domain. The rings $\mathbb F_2[X]$ and $\mathbb F_2[Y]$ are clearly Krull domains living in the common field $\mathbb F_2(X,Y)$, and their intersection is $\mathbb F_2$. So $\mathbb F_2$ *must* be a Krull domain, but I can't see why.

Comment: every UFD is a krull domain. [See](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/22669/why-is-ufd-a-krull-domain)

Comment: Let me ask you a related question: do you consider a field to be a UFD? A field has no irreducible elements (the set of irreducible elements is empty), so at best it is a degenerate example of a UFD and you would consider it to be a UFD just to have cleaner statements of theorems. In your concerns, an integral domain that is not a field does not become a Krull domain using an empty set of valuations since the valuations are defined *on the fraction field*, so the intersection in property 2 is the fraction field.

Comment: Every UFD is a field (unless there are conventions that I'm unaware of), but that doesn't answer the question to my satisfaction. Any theorem that proves that a UFD is a Krull domain will also prove that a field is a Krull domain, and explaining  the theorem in the field case *would* answer the question to my satisfaction. (For instance. There should be a simpler explanation though.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to exclude the fields from the class of Krull domains as Larsen and McCarthy did in their [*Multiplicative Theory of Ideals*](https://books.google.ro/books?id=jPCin77MOjQC&pg=PA172&lpg=PA172&dq=%22However,+we+choose+to+exclude+fields+from+the+class+of%22&source=bl&ots=AuakkPaf0C&sig=QhYxfPKeK_k7E8sFoBoimRra0DY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=kVqZVdfIG4m8UZSYsyA&ved=0CBMQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q=%22However%2C%20we%20choose%20to%20exclude%20fields%20from%20the%20class%20of%22&f=true).

A reason could be the following: if a field $K$ would be a Krull domain, then by definition it is an intersection of DVRs contained in $K$, that is, equal to $K$, but a field is not a [DVR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_valuation_ring). (In some sense we consider the DVRs as being the "smallest" examples of Krull domains.)

Comment: That makes sense to me. With this stipulation, it is no longer true that the intersection of two Krull domains contained in a common field is a Krull domain. Do you know if that claim is true provided the intersection is not a field?

Comment: @user134824 This holds for an arbitrary family of Krull domains satisfying the finite character property.

Comment: That's good to know; I wasn't aware of the finite character property. I'll have to think about that. However, isn't it true that the set $\{\mathbb F_2[X],\mathbb F_2[Y]\}$ has the finite character property but that the conclusion of the claim does not hold, i.e., that $\mathbb F_2[X]\cap\mathbb F_2[Y]=\mathbb F_2$ is not a Krull domain under our (revised) definition?

Comment: @user134824 If we decide to exclude the fields then the property holds under assumption that the intersection is not a field.

Comment: Oh, I see. I guess it was unclear to me what you meant by "this". Thanks.

Comment: (For correctness: I should have written the *power set* of $\{\mathbb F_2[X],\mathbb F_2[Y]\}$, not the set itself. The former has the finite intersection property and the latter does not.)